# ¿Como puede seleccionar un elemento de una listbox y hacer que cuando presiones un boton encadenarlo a un evento?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, python-3.8

Lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario pueda seleccionar un elemento de la listbox y que cuando presiones enter, suceda un evento.

No tengo un codigo en si, solo quiero que alguien me pueda sacar de esta duda ya que lo que quiero hacer es que haya 3 elementos y que el usuario pueda seleccionarlos y que al presionar enter, aparezca una ventana que diga que haz seleccionado ese mismo elemento.

Answer (score 0):

**Puedes hacerlo manejando los eventos `"<<ListboxSelect>>"` y `"<Return>"`**.

Por ejemplo, tu *script* puede empezar así:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

root = Tk()

texto_seleccionado = 'Ningún elemento Seleccionado'

root.bind('<Return>', lambda ev:showinfo(title='Texto Seleccionado', message=texto_seleccionado))

root.mainloop()
```

En este ejemplo `root` es el formulario de la aplicación, y mediante su método `bind` puedes registrar un *manejador de eventos*. Para que el *evento manejado* sea **pulsar enter** el primer argumento del método `bind` debe ser `"<Return>"`. El segundo argumento de este método es la función que se ejecutará al *dispararse el evento return*.

Todos los *manejadores de eventos* son funciones que reciben un argumento (yo lo he llamado `ev` pero este identificador es arbitrario y puedes llamarlo como quieras). En el ejemplo he utilizado la función anónima `lambda ev:showinfo(title='Texto Seleccionado', message=texto_seleccionado)`, pero podrías haberla definido y registrado como *manejador del evento return* así:

```
def mostrar_mensaje(ev):
    showinfo(title='Texto Seleccionado', message=texto_seleccionado)

root.bind('<Return>', mostrar_mensaje)
```

Dicho esto, lo que sucede al *presionar la tecla enter* es que se muestra un mensaje con el texto `"Ningún elemento Seleccionado"`, que es el valor de la variable `texto_seleccionado`.

**Puedes añadir un `Listbox` y que suceda algo cuando haces click en uno de sus elementos**. Por ejemplo:

```
listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

listbox.insert(END, 'Primer Elemento de la Lista')
listbox.insert(END, 'Segundo Elemento de la Lista')
```

Ahora que la aplicación muestra un *widget Listbox de tkinter* identificado como `listbox` que contiene dos *items* puedes, de nuevo, utilizar el método `bind` para registrar un *manejador de eventos*, en este caso asociado al evento `"<<ListboxSelect>>"`:

```
def seleccionar(ev):
    pass

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', seleccionar)
```

Cuando se seleccione un elemento de `listbox` se va a ejecutar la función `seleccionar`, de modo que **en esta función puedes modificar el valor de la variable `texto_seleccionado`:**

```
def seleccionar(ev):
    global texto_seleccionado
    texto_seleccionado = ev.widget.get(ANCHOR)
```

`ev.widget` es el *widget* que ha disparado el evento, es decir, `ev.widget == listbox`. Para obtener el texto del elemento seleccionado utiliza su método `get` pasando como parámetro la variable `ANCHOR` (`tkinter.ANCHOR`): `ev.widget.get(ANCHOR)`.

Asignando este valor a la *variable global* `texto_seleccionado`, al *pulsar enter* se mostrará un mensaje con el nuevo valor de esta variable (ya que previamente habíamos definido `root.bind('<Return>', lambda ev:showinfo(title='Texto Seleccionado', message=texto_seleccionado))`).

**El código final de este ejemplo es el siguiente:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


def seleccionar(ev):
    global texto_seleccionado
    texto_seleccionado = ev.widget.get(ANCHOR)


root = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

listbox.insert(END, 'Primer Elemento de la Lista')
listbox.insert(END, 'Segundo Elemento de la Lista')

texto_seleccionado = 'Ningún elemento Seleccionado'

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', seleccionar)

root.bind('<Return>', lambda ev:showinfo(title='Texto Seleccionado', message=texto_seleccionado))

root.mainloop()
```

Un saludo!